# I want to use the thumbnails of nested slider jquery as menu like buttons

Tags: javascript, css, nested, jssor

I am using Nested slider jquery right now. Now my requirement is I have to display 8 categories of images to display. So I am thinking if i can extend the thumbnails(after removing background images) from 3 to 8 and change its positioning and width of the whole set of thumbnails container above the main slideshow box so that it looks like a menu bar. So when i click any text it displays respective set of images.

Comment: how nice. have you any code to go with your question?

Comment: @Rachel Gallen: The code I am editing is too huge to paste. I copied the original code from http://www.jssor.com/testcase/nested-slider-loop-through.source.html .

Comment: Please helpme solving this issue.

Comment: i think you are overcompicating things. there are easier ways to do a gallery. look at this http://jsbin.com/zufoleqelu/edit?html,css,output

Comment: output http://output.jsbin.com/zufoleqelu

Comment: Ya the code is good to go with. But here if i hover on any thumbnail it displays that particular single image. What i want is to display category of images on click/hover event. Like here if i hover on a single thumbnail it should display more than one image falling in that particular category. Similarly for other thumbnails. How can I achieve that? I have done it for my website http://www.safehandindia.com/orgch/about-us.html The only issue I am facing here is I am not able to make it auto play. Can u help me with that?

Comment: Please help me with the auto play code for that url. @ Rachel Gallen . I would be eally grateful

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pnsb4Loa/

Comment: Thanks @RachelGallen for the code. But I want Category Image Slideshow. LIke if i click on any category the slideshow should display the images falling under that category and so on. And it should also auto play. I do not know jquery.

Comment: learn it. all you have to do is include the script. its easy. you can get lot of help from here. you can use this for any category

Comment: Alright @RachelGallen. Thank you.